# Open google map in new window.

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-maps

I have created a Google Map API and I would like to open it in a new tab(Window). May I know what's wrong with my code? I can open a new tab, but I can't display the Google Map.

Below are my code. Thanks!

```
    function newWindow() 
    { 
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.7,40);
     var myOptions = 
        {
         zoom: 2,
         center: myLatlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
    } 

<A HREF="" onclick="window.open('javascript:newWindow()')" >New Map(In new window)</A>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) takes a URL as a parameter. Your `newWindow()` function does not return anything, let alone a URL.
2. You need to call `window.open()` with a valid URL passed in, which takes care of setting up the map itself.
3. If you're going to attach an event handler inline, do it right:

   `<a onclick="window.open('some_url_here'); return false;">...</a>.`

That said, in the interest of unobtrusive JavaScript, you should really attach JS event handlers using your external JS code.

---

Perhaps you want to open your map in a modal dialog instead?

Comment: Oh okay thanks! Previously I have came across a website that do something like onclick="window.open('javascript:function()'); That was why I thought that I could do function inside window.open. Thanks for resolving for me.

Comment: @KennC: that only worked because that function returned a URL. Also, I'm sure you don't mean `onclick="window.open('javascript:function()');` because `function` is a keyword in JS :) ... _also_, you're already in a JS context when writing `onclick="/* js context here */"`, so writing `javascript:function()` inside of that is actually a syntax error.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yah and I don't mean the word function. =) Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

the variable for window.open is the url

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('stackoverflow.com')">New Map(In new window)</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a solution for your problem. The first error here is that the context in new window is different from the old window.

```
var w = window.open('', '_blank', options);
```

**w** is a Window object different from the **window**. Empty URL create an empty page "about:blank", and since there is no domain, you have read/write access to **w.document**.
So something like this:

```
function newWindowMap(latitude, longitude) {
    var w = window.open('', '_blank'); //you must use predefined window name here for IE.
    var head = w.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    //Give some information about the map:
    w.document.createElement('input');
    //Place ID, value and type='hidden' here
    var loadScript = w.document.createElement('script');
    loadScript.src = '...'; //Link to script that load google maps from hidden elements.
    var googleMapScript = w.document.createElement('script');
    googleMapScript.src = '...'; //Link to google maps js, use callback=... URL parameter to setup the calling function after google maps load.
    head.appendChild(loadScript);
    head.appendChild(googleMapScript);
}
```

Now the whole loadScript will be in context of the new window and google map will call a function from it, when it finished loading. You can create new **div** dynamically and use it to create a map.