# custom google map in new window

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I try to finish code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348030/6639518).
But something goes wrong as I am new in java-scripting, My guess is the map simply does not loading properly. DIV is created in new tab, text as well. Please help me to open custom map in new tab.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  function newWindow() {
    var w = window.open('', '_blank'); //you must use predefined window name here for IE.
    var head = w.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    //Give some information about the map:
    w.document.head.innerHTML = '<title>Simple Map</title></head>';
    w.document.body.innerHTML = '<body><H1>Loading</H1><div id="map_canvas" style="display: block; width: 500px; height: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></div></body>';

    var loadScript = w.document.createElement('script');
    //Link to script that load google maps from hidden elements.
    loadScript.type = "text/javascript";
    loadScript.async = true;
    loadScript.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";

    var googleMapScript = w.document.createElement('script');
    //Link to google maps js, use callback=... URL parameter to setup the calling function after google maps load.
    googleMapScript.type = "text/javascript";
    googleMapScript.async = true;
    googleMapScript.text = 'var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.4,30.50),zoom: 6, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}; var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);';

    head.appendChild(loadScript);
    head.appendChild(googleMapScript);
  }
  //addLoadEvent(loadScript);
  </script>
  <button onclick="newWindow()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't define the initialize() function in your second script object.

The code should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    function newWindow() {
        var w = window.open('', '_blank'); //you must use predefined window name here for IE.
        var head = w.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

        //Give some information about the map:
        w.document.head.innerHTML = '<title>Simple Map</title></head>';
        w.document.body.innerHTML = '<body><H1>Loading</H1><div id="map_canvas" style="display: block; width: 500px; height: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></div></body>';

        var loadScript = w.document.createElement('script');
        //Link to script that load google maps from hidden elements.
        loadScript.type = "text/javascript";
        loadScript.async = true;
        loadScript.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";

        var googleMapScript = w.document.createElement('script');
        //Link to google maps js, use callback=... URL parameter to setup the calling function after google maps load.
        googleMapScript.type = "text/javascript";
        googleMapScript.async = false;
        googleMapScript.text = 'function initialize() {var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.4,30.50),zoom: 6, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}; var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);}';

        head.appendChild(loadScript);
        head.appendChild(googleMapScript);
    }
    //addLoadEvent(loadScript);
</script>
<button onclick="newWindow()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the example on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/loyaca/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks Xomena, that works and for the intercative coding site too!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer. This is a SO way to say thanks. :)